# Should bash shells be replaced with the new patched version?

Tags: security, bash

This question has generated a lot of downvoting on three SE sites so let me try to explain where it comes from.

*The magnitude of the bash "shellshock" problem may turn out to be larger than anything since Y2K.*

Having been part of a complete replacement of a large data center for Y2K, I'm alarmed at the panic that's been generated over shellshock (appropo name, btw). I'm concerned that rushing in quick fixes without extensive planning and testing is going to create far greater problems than the one we think we are facing.

*For Y2K, we learned that the date code fixes were the easy part.*

The massively more complex, error-prone, and unscheduled downtime-producing part was discovering and fixing/mitigating the failures in other software caused by the fixes. Some of these weren't discovered until the new systems had been in production for months. Despite a herculean effort, a few even resulted in organizational policy changes because they were too disruptive to fix.

*I am not suggesting that security-patching is unadvisable.*

However, in this case only, I have noticed a suspicious series of events culminating in not just another run-of-the-mill vulnerability, but one demanding massive updating of systems affecting virtually every person using a computer on the planet.

*The vulnerability is real. But is the need for instant action?*

It is this combination of factors that gives me pause...

**A fact...**

- ["Bash is standard on Mac OS X and many Linux systems"](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/shellshock-flaw-day2,news-19618.html)

**A timeline...**

- [Oct 2012 - "Apple is added to the NSA’s list of penetrated servers"](http://www.rawstory.com/rs/2014/02/speculation-emerges-apple-security-flaw-may-be-tied-to-nsa-spying/)
- [Dec 2013 - Apple Says It Has Never Worked With NSA...](http://techcrunch.com/2013/12/31/apple-says-it-has-never-worked-with-nsa-to-create-iphone-backdoors-is-unaware-of-alleged-dropoutjeep-snooping-program/)
- [Sep 19, 2014 - Likely that NSA has now demanded Apple's data and they are resisting](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2014/09/19/did-the-nsa-demand-apples-data)
- [Sep 24, 2014 - US-CERT is aware of a Bash vulnerability affecting Unix-based operating systems such as Linux and Mac OS X](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2014/09/24/Bourne-Again-Shell-Bash-Remote-Code-Execution-Vulnerability)

**Ramifications...**

- The Bash shellshock "vulnerability" has been a "feature" of Bash for 22 years. You'd think in all that time, in all those high-security environments that run Unix or Linux, someone would have worried about misuse.
- Now, every installation of Bash in the world is about to be replaced.
- Though Bash is open-source, few people actually take the time to study the code of such large and complex programs.
- Bash is written in C, which supports embedded assembly-language code. Code that even fewer programmers have the skills to read.
- Bash is written in C, which easily supports treating any block of binary, such as something labeled as data or a small image, as code.
- Thus, a skilled programmer could hide "backdoor" code in plain sight, and it probably wouldn't be discovered unless it caused an error of some kind.

**The claim...**

"[US-CERT recommends users and administrators review TA14-268A, Vulnerability Note VU#252743 and the Redhat Security Blog (link is external) for additional details and to refer to their respective Linux or Unix-based OS vendor(s) for an appropriate patch.](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/current-activity/2014/09/24/Bourne-Again-Shell-Bash-Remote-Code-Execution-Vulnerability)"

**The question...**

Should bash shells be replaced with these new patched versions?

**RESOURCES**

- [bash patching team discussion on insecure.org](http://insecure.org/search.html?cx=partner-pub-0078565546631069%3Abx60rb-fytx&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=BASH_FUNCDEFS&sa=Search&siteurl=seclists.org%2Foss-sec%2F2014%2Fq3%2F666&ref=seclists.org%2Foss-sec%2F2014%2Fq3%2F650&ss=)
- [Apple: “The vast majority of OS X users are not at risk to recently reported bash vulnerabilities,"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146913/83608)
- [Red Security Blog: Bash specially-crafted environment variables code injection attack](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/)

---

### Update 2017-09-28

After 3 years, someone actually found a sliver of usefulness in this and upvoted the question?

Well then, let me a mea culpa...

The above's focus on the circumstances surrounding Shellshock's announcement were a knee-jerk reaction on my part. A reaction I regret. While factual, the "conspiratorial" tone produced a backlash that obscured anything of value. I leave it intact only so that the many good comments make sense.

Enough new versions of most of the software involved have been released and well vetted by now that Shellshock may only still be of some concern to those running low-powered systems that must use older software. My alarm at the time was over the dangers of blindly removing 22 year old functionality from those systems with no analysis of the impact. Apparently, it turns out that the functionality was rarely, if ever, used.

Comment: @JakeGould Sorry, forgot to reply. Please see last night's edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should. Even in the very worst case, you're trading a known-exploitable version of a program for one that is theoretically exploitable only by whoever crafted a potential back door.

Tons of people know about the current problem and can use it against you right now, but presumably few people know about this hypothetical back door that may not even exist.

The decision seems like an easy one to me...at least if you're referring to the official patch released by the vendor of your OS. As for third-party patches, it comes down to a question of trust.

Personally, I will be patching, but I will be waiting for Apple, or at the very least for a trusted repository (Homebrew etc) to release a 3.2-series version of bash with the fix.

Comment: Even if the chances are small, you still generally want to patch security vulnerabilities. The other post, for example, focuses on direct exploitation from external systems. But what about privilege escalation? Are you absolutely positive that there are no setuid executables on your system that execute anything through bash in a way that would allow their environment variables to be influenced maliciously?

Comment: @JakeGould, you keep saying that people's chances of being affected or close to nil, but all it takes is using the Web Sharing feature to open up the system to exploit. Apache uses bash for all manner of stuff. Lots of web devs and programmers use local web hosting for development, wikis, Bugzilla instances and the like. "Pretty much zilch" is a gross oversimplification of the issue. Web Sharing while working on a public (or hacked) network and all bets are off.

Comment: @JakeGould, having a vulnerable bash would still open you up to the possibility of privilege escalation as I commented above (but admittedly forgot to at-tag you in). Do you trust that all of your setuid programs never execute anything via bash with environment variables that could be under user control? And that you will never install such programs in the future without remembering to check? (`sudo find /usr /Applications/ -perm +6000`) I agree that there's no need to *panic*, but implying that people simply should not patch seems misguided.

Comment: I agree with both the issue that mod_cgi is not installed by default (but that does not imply that it might not be installed and used) and that escalation is a risk. I've patched my system. Was I panicking? Heck, no. That said, I see no harm whatsoever in patching the system ahead of Apple lackadaisically rolling out its own fixes. Apple tends to be pretty slow about such matters.

Comment: "and how the Apache risk is really non-existent in modern Linux servers"

You obviously do not run a cPanel shared server on which 'CGI Center' is an expected feature by Web 1.0-oriented users. (I run a hosting company.) My CentOS servers are patched and not vulnerable. Honestly, I don't know why you think I don't feel fine. I feel wonderful. As for RH's non-issue: "Because of the pervasive use of the Bash shell, this issue is quite serious and should be treated as such." From here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223

Comment: @TraneFrancks, it's OK, bash is only referenced by 146 executables in the standard bin directories alone (`sudo find /usr/bin /usr/sbin/ /sbin/ -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 egrep -l "/bin/(ba){0,1}sh" | wc -l`). The question asked was whether bash should be patched, but the argument being made here is that a heavily-used binary apparently shouldn't be patched because it's not (usually) *remotely* exploitable. I throw up my hands at this point.

Comment: I'm kind of throwing up my hands, too, @ScottDudley. I'm soundly of the opinion that patching first is a good idea because Apple has such a poor track record of rolling fixes out in a timely manner. Patching the binaries in `/bin` gives the luxury of a secure system - both before AND after Apple gets a Round-To-It.

Comment: I too throw up my hands in defeat. I tried. Time will tell. Note that I've accepted @ScottDudley 's answer. Go upgrade your binaries. Let me know how it goes.