# How can I fix this CODESIGNING error?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

After having successfully compiled bash and sh for OS X Mavericks our OS X Server's System Log is flooded every 2 or 3 seconds with:

```
... kernel[0]: CODESIGNING: rejected new signature for architecture 16777223 of file /bin/sh
... kernel[0]: proc 59029: load code signature error 4 for file "sh"
```

There are no complaints about bash, only sh.

What is going on and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: This is one of many reasons why system binaries shouldn't be replaced in general.

Comment: @grgarside oh for an ideal world - without vulnerabilities like ShellShock and with plenty of time to await Apple fixes; which we didn't feel we had to protect the integrity of our OS X Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have observed the same error when deploying my own signed apps. It appears that if you mv/cp a new binary over an existing signed one, the kernel does not keep track of this very well and starts generating these errors.
I have found that this does not occur if the new binary is installed as part of a package, or if the original binary is deleted first and then the new binary put in place.
Additionally once in this situation, a reboot fixes the issue, presumably as the kernel codesigning table is stored in memory. I appreciate rebooting may not be an option in a server environment.

Comment: Rebooting fixed the problem. i.e. no more CODESIGNING errors were logged wrt the new `/bin/sh` after restart. I was nervous of rebooting with an iffy `sh` in case I locked myself out of our server. But I needn't have worried. The OS X Server is running smoothly. Thanks to @SillyWilly for confidence-enabling answer. BTW the whole exercise was as a fix to the "shell shock" vulnerability. (See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-shellshock-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-an)