# Will recompiling bash to avoid Shellshock cause more harm than good

Tags: macos, security, bash

I wasn't particularly worried about Shellshock until I learned that a malicious DHCP server may be able to exploit my DHCP client to run arbitrary code on my system. It's not clear to me whether Macs are vulnerable, but if so, I want to fix it ASAP.

That said, the version of `/bin/bash` on my Mac is code-signed by Apple.

```
$ spctl --verbose --assess --type execute /bin/bash
/bin/bash: accepted
source=Apple System
```

If I follow [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146851/56476) and replace Apple's `/bin/bash` with one that I compile myself (hence *not* code-signed by Apple), am I setting myself up for trouble?

Comment: You could get a developer ID and sign the re-compiled `bash` as yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macs don't use Bash for DHCP, so that particular vulnerability does not apply. Unless you run a vulnerable web server or have restricted remote access accounts, it's not worth the trouble to recompile Bash on OS X.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether Macs use Bash for DHCP. Glad to hear they don't!