# How can I patch Mac is OS X 10.4.11 with Bash version 2.05b.0(1) for Shellshock bug?

Tags: macos

My Mac is OS X 10.4.11 with Bash version 2.05b.0(1)-Release (PowerPC-Apple-Darwin8.0) on a PowerMac. It is vulnerable and need to be patched. This Mac uses Filemaker 8.5 pro client and hosts the remote files sitting on the Windows server. It also communicates with the MYSQL DB which is again hosted on the Windows server

What is the possibility of my Mac being affected by this bug?

I do not see any patches for this version of bash.

I am not good in handling Mac OS compilation and installing. We are due to upgrade our Macs soon (early next year).

What might I do for now?

Comment: Recompile bash if you have gcc installed. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147194/60561 -- http://tenfourfox.blogspot.com/2014/09/bashing-bash-one-more-time-updated.html

Comment: You probably have bigger security concerns if you're still on 10.4 though...

Answer (score 1):

http://tenfourfox.blogspot.com/2014/09/bashing-bash-one-more-time-updated.html

If you go to this site, there's a precompiled binary that works for 10.4 (PowerPC).  I'm using it and it works well.

Comment: Downloading binaries from random sites is an excellent way to have your system get owned. Just sayin'. If the user has the skills to compile his own binaries from official Apple or GNU source, that is absolutely the way to go.