# Are there any disadvantages to using the brew version of bash for /bin/sh?

Tags: security, bash

I have patched bash & sh with the latest patches [as described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-shellshock-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-an), but now have some issues with some things in my dotfiles (particularly the loading of rvm and some custom functions and completions).

I don't have the issues if I just use the brew version of bash as both `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`, but I'm wondering if I might run into other problems with system stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise against making the Homebrew installation of bash your system-wide `bash` or `sh` command. However it should be fine to use as your personal shell.

Homebrew provides [a vanilla installation of Gnu Bash](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/bash.rb#L7). You will be missing any Apple additions to the shell that are provided if you use the Apple-supplied `bash` or `sh` binaries or source code from Apple's [opensource.apple.com site](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/bash/). Any OS-level shell script provided by Apple may be relying on those Apple extension and changes to function.

Homebrew also installs, by default, a 4.3.x version of bash:

```
> brew info bash
bash: stable 4.3.24 (bottled), HEAD
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/bash.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: readline ✘
==> Caveats
In order to use this build of bash as your login shell,
it must be added to /etc/shells.
```

This is a significantly different version than the 3.2.x version that ships with OS X 10.9.x. It is not 100% backwards compatible with pre 4 versions. For example [substring extraction on positional parameters indexing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html#SUBSTREXTREF4) changed from 3 to 4. It could break system-level scripts.

Both of those reasons can lead to inoperable system scripts on your Mac if you switch to Homebrew's versions of `bash` and `sh` for anything other than your personal shell. You can make your personal shell the Homebrew `bash` shell by running:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

and then logging out and logging back in. This should be relatively safe for the stable operation of your machine.

If the above `chsh` command fails saying `/usr/local/bin/bash` is not an acceptable shell you'll need to add it to the list in `/etc/shells` by running:

```
sudo vim /etc/shells
```

It should be added on a new line in the file like so:

```
> cat /etc/shells
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/bash
```