# Recompiling bash to avoid shellshock seems to have messed up bash

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I probably shouldn't have even messed with it, but I followed the instructions to recompile bash here:
[How do I recompile Bash to avoid Shellshock (the remote exploit CVE-2014-6271 and CVE-2014-7169)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-shellshock-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-an/146851#146851)

Following that recompile, if I run something like wget from terminal, I get the following:
-bash: wget: command not found

And that's not the only one. A lot of the usual bash commands seems to have disappeared for me. How do I do a complete revert of bash back to normal but with the current apple supported bash patch(es)? Is there a better way to fix my problem?

Comment: I would just install the Apple bash update as per the main answer in the question you linked to http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146851/237

Comment: This seems to be more of an issue with your `PATH` than with the shell. What does `echo $PATH`  return?

Comment: patrix. I've been doing some stuff with python, so it seems to be this complicated path here which may indeed be the problem:

$ echo $PATH
/Users/Luke/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

At the same time, I'm not sure that I have wget installed, but I thought that I did. How can I easily check that, in light of this path? 
$ which ls ; echo $?
/bin/ls
0
$ which no_such_executable ; echo $?
1

Comment: Path looks ok to me, I would assume that you haven't install `wget` in the first place (run `sudo find / -name wget` and have a cup of tea whil it runs to verify). Which other "usual" bash commands seem to have disappeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `wget` isn't installed by default on Mavericks. You could install it through homebrew though.

If you installed `wget` yourself at one time then you may just need to adjust your `$PATH` to *find* it again.

`PATH=/path/to/wget:"${PATH}"`

Take a look in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` to see what tools are installed and try one of them to see if `Bash` is working correctly.

Comment: Turns out wget was not installed. Bash does seem to be working fine. Thanks for the help! 
One final question regarding the bash-fix, can I remove the bash-fix folder in my root directory that the patching steps created? I would think so, but I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: Your folder named 'bash-fix' can be removed. sudo rm -rf bash-fix