# How to mitigate Bash risk while waiting for a patch (sans a recompile)?

Tags: macos, security, bash

This is related to [How do I recompile Bash to avoid the remote exploit CVE-2014-6271 and CVE-2014-7169?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146849/how-do-i-recompile-bash-to-avoid-the-remote-exploit-cve-2014-6271-and-cve-2014-7), [Are Macs vulnerable to the Bash shellshock bug?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146893/are-macs-vulnerable-to-the-bash-shellshock-bug) and [Are Bash, Bourne, and Korn shells compiled into one binary in OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89311/are-bash-bourne-and-korn-shells-compiled-into-one-binary-in-osx).

Apple has not released a patch for 10.8.5, and there's no telling if/when they will patch the defective software.

I don't want to download and compile a version of Bash because version headaches. For example, I might place a new copy in `/usr/local/bin`, but other software may be hardwired for Bash in `/usr`. Or I might replace `/bin/bash` and some unintended consequence might arise, like Apple refusing to update my version of Bash.

How does one mitigate the vulnerable *without* compiling and patching?

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for Mountain Lion, see http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1768.